# If ...Else If wont work

Tags: javascript, html, css, logical-operators

This is how it worked: changing from 
Issue: 
      x==0||1 to x==0||x==1 
etc.

This is running from an .html

```
<body>   
<div class="" id="pimg1">

      </body><script>

      var x=new Date().getMonth();

     if (x == 0||x == 5||x == 2){document.getElementById('pimg1').className='pimg1';}
      else 
      if (x == 3||x == 4){document.getElementById('pimg1').className="pimg1a";}
      else 
      if (x == 6||x == 7||x == 8){document.getElementById('pimg1').className='pimg1b';}
      else                            {document.getElementById('pimg1').className='pimg1c';}


    </script></html>
```

External css:

```
.pimg1{
   background-image: url('images/style1.jpg');/*Zone 1*/}
  .pimg1a{
 background-image: url('images/style2.jpg');/*Zone 1*/}
 .pimg1b{
background-image: url('images/style3.jpg');/*Zone 1*/}
    .pimg1c{
background-image: url('images/style4.jpg');/*Zone 1*/}
```

Comment: what langage is this ?

Comment: `(x == 0||9||2)` => `(x == 0|| x==9|| x==2)`

Comment: this is javascript put (not in a javascript block) directly inside a html file, meaning it is considered text, not code

Comment: you are using javascript inside html's 'div' element. this will not work, unless you separate javascript in it's own <script> tags.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]? The code here has issues, as you can see by the comments. Also, show the loop that won't trigger. There is no loop here.

Comment: javascript in html ;)

Comment: `x == 0||9||2` doesn't work. It returns `true` if `x === 0` else `9 `

Comment: Voted to close due to a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error

Comment: indentation and code formatting will make your debugging easier

Comment: This is beautiful.

Comment: Mixture of JS, HTML, CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, put the javascript code between a `<script></script>` tag because javascript code will not run in an html `<div></div>` tag.

Then, instead of `x == 0||9||2`, use `x == 0 || x == 9 || x == 2`.

Kindly indent your code for easier readability. The `||` operator looks for conditions on the let and right sides. `9` is not a condition, neither is `2`. When you put `x == 9 || x == 2`, you're saying check the condition on the left, if not true check the one on the right. If one is true, then we're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

We can not use css into `<script>` tag also remove `<script>` tag from `<div>` tag like as follows :

```
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .pimg1 {
      background-image: url('images/style1.jpg');
      /*Zone 1*/
    }
    .pimg1a {
      background-image: url('images/style2.jpg');
      /*Zone 1*/
    }
    .pimg1b {
      background-image: url('images/style3.jpg');
      /*Zone 1*/
    }
    .pimg1c {
      background-image: url('images/style4.jpg');
      /*Zone 1*/
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="" id="pimg1"></div>
  <script>
    var x = new Date().getMonth();
    if (x == 0 || 9 || 2) {
      document.getElementById('pimg1').className = 'pimg1';
    } else if (x == 3 || 5) {
      document.getElementById('pimg1').className = "pimg1a";
    } else if (x == 6 || 1 || 8) {
      document.getElementById('pimg1').className = 'pimg1b';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('pimg1').className = 'pimg1c';
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you even know how to write a basic `if` condition?